# Как удалить model в Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel

Как удалить model в laravel созданный через cmd.exe

```
php artisan make:model static
```

Comment: `artisan` всего навсего генератор кода, хоть и мощный. Ищите файл модели в папке `app`.

Comment: Ну ведь он вносит название классов в определенные файлы, тобишь пространство имен? Вот и вопрос, как удалить с помощью командной строки, код который он вносил во время создания этого самого кода.

Comment: Да, в конфиг. Нужно уметь разбираться куда что вносит, а не смотреть на laravel, как на чёрный шайтан ящик.

Comment: Насколько я помню, при создании модели никуда ничего не вносится. Достаточно удаление файла самой модели.

Comment: Вывести список всех команад artisan: `php artisan list`. Получить справку по конкретной команде: `php artisan help make`.

Answer (score 3):

Просто удалите файл самой модели.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию artisan скрипт создает модели в директории app. Исходя приведенного вами кода нужно удалить файл по данному пути app/Static.php